# Debian Jessie start rpcbind and nfs-common at boot with systemd

Tags: debian, boot, systemd, nfs, autofs

On my Raspbian (based on Debian Jessie), I need to start at boot `rpcbind` and `nfs-common` services because I need them to start `autofs` at boot for a NFS mount.

Since Debian Jessie now has moved to `systemd`, I want to know the best way to start those 3 services (rpcbind, nfs-commond, autofs) in the correct order to avoid issues.

If I manually mount the NFS share it works. And it also works when using the autofs service with rpcbind and nfs-common already up and running.

autofs uses a systemd unit script. About the other 2 services, should I make init.d scripts or do I have to create systemd unit files? How can I write them?

Comment: hint: the fact that Jessie moved by default to systemd, does not oblige you to move to *now*. I am giving it some more time.

Comment: It should all just work, whether you use System V init or systemd, so you shouldn't need to write any scripts. `autofs` provides a systemd unit as you point out, and even though `rpcbind` and `nfs-common` don't (yet), their `init.d` scripts are taken into account by systemd. (I use all three and didn't need to fix anything after upgrading to Jessie and switching to systemd.) Is there a specific problem you're seeing?

Comment: @StephenKitt I only need to be sure that `rpcbind` and `nfs-common` are loaded before `autofs`. It should be easier to do with systemd unit file since you can specify dependecies and so the correct order. But I never used systemd before and never wrote a systemd unit file, so I don't know how to do that the right way. Otherwise how is it possible to assure this with init.d?

Comment: Have you tried it? With `init.d`, the order is defined by the `BEGIN INIT INFO` comments (`Required-Start`, `Should-Start` etc.). On my systems, running System V init or systemd, the scripts are automatically ordered such that `rpcbind` and `nfs-common` are started before `autofs`.

Comment: @StephenKitt I tried your solution, so I used `sudo update-rc.d rpcbind enable` and `sudo update-rc.d nfs-common enable`. Only `nfs-common` starts at boot correctly but `rpcbind` not. So I tried also `sudo update-rc.d rpcbind defaults` but no way. The only workaround is to add `service rpcbind start` inside the `/etc/rc.local` script but it's not the proper way... Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

The reason for the problem is the lack of *systemd* configuration files. Base on a [post by Matt Grant](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2014/05/msg00618.html) on `debian-devel` these are the steps you need to perform.

## 1. Create `/etc/systemd/system/nfs-common.service`

```
cat >/etc/systemd/system/nfs-common.service <<\EOF
[Unit]
Description=NFS Common daemons
Wants=remote-fs-pre.target
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/nfs-common start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/nfs-common stop

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
EOF
```

## 2. Create `/etc/systemd/system/rpcbind.service`

```
cat >/etc/systemd/system/rpcbind.service <<\EOF
[Unit]
Description=RPC bind portmap service
After=systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
Wants=remote-fs-pre.target
Before=remote-fs-pre.target
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
ExecStart=/sbin/rpcbind -f -w
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
Alias=portmap
EOF
```

## 3. Create `/etc/tmpfiles.d/rpcbind.conf`

```
cat >/etc/tmpfiles.d/rpcbind.conf <<\EOF
#Type Path        Mode UID  GID  Age Argument
d     /run/rpcbind 0755 root root - -
f     /run/rpcbind/rpcbind.xdr 0600 root root - -
f     /run/rpcbind/portmap.xdr 0600 root root - -
EOF
```

## 4. Configure the services to run at startup

```
systemctl enable rpcbind.service
systemctl enable nfs-common
```