# start script at boot for kali linux

Tags: shell-script, boot, kali-linux, startup

I'm running Kali Linux 2018.1 on a VM.  I want to run a bunch of commands that I have stored in the file start.sh at startup.  I know how to do this on a normal distro by going into `/etc/rc.local`, but that doesn't exist in Kali.

Here are some of the commands I want to run.

```
apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
openvas-start
/etc/init.d/nessusd start
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Guys (and girls), not every question which mentions kali needs to be closed as a duplicate of that "kali - why won't people help me". This question is well defined, answerable, can help other people, and really isn't even kali specific.

Comment: I cant decide wether I prefer the method here. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263331/debian-jessie-start-rpcbind-and-nfs-common-at-boot-with-systemd

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add this script to `/etc/crontab`:

```
@reboot /path/to/your/start.sh
```

From [man 5 crontab](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html):

```
@reboot    :    Run once after reboot.
```

Comment: I'm in the file /etc/crontab.  Do I add "@reboot/path/start.sh" to the end of the file and then add "@reboot : Run once after reboot" after that?

Comment: Yes, add script in format that I've written.

Comment: This is great-- I personally never knew crontab had support for scheduled tasks on reboot.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, found a solution in a post elsewhere.

Summary:

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service
```

Then add the following content to it.

```
[Unit]
 Description=/etc/rc.local Compatibility
 ConditionPathExists=/etc/rc.local

[Service]
 Type=forking
 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start
 TimeoutSec=0
 StandardOutput=tty
 RemainAfterExit=yes
 SysVStartPriority=99

[Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note: Starting with 16.10, Ubuntu doesn’t ship with /etc/rc.local file anymore. Same thing for other distributions like Kali. You can create the file by executing this command.

```
printf '%s\n' '#!/bin/bash' 'exit 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/rc.local
```

Then add execute permission to /etc/rc.local file.

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

After that, enable the service on system boot:

```
sudo systemctl enable rc-local
```

Finally, start the service and check its status:

```
sudo systemctl start rc-local.service
sudo systemctl status rc-local.service
```

The complete post in https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd